# How do you join items in array based upon their key?

Tags: javascript

I want to join items in an array based upon their key. I ran thru the lodash library trying `_.join`, `_.merge()`, `_.groupBy()` but no of those seem to work. How do you join items in array based upon their key?

```
var myArray = [
  {name: 'cheesesteak'},
  {name: 'hamburger'},
  {name: 'pork roll'}
];

var jawn = myArray.join();

console.log(jawn);
```

Ideal output is...

```
"chessesteak, hamburger, pork roll"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** with [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for generating string array and then apply **[`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** method.

```js
var myArray = [{
  name: 'cheesesteak'
}, {
  name: 'hamburger'
}, {
  name: 'pork roll'
}];

var jawn = myArray.map(v => v.name).join();

console.log(jawn);
```

---

Since arrow function only supports in latest browsers use normal function in older browser and also check [polyfill option of map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill).

```js
var myArray = [{
  name: 'cheesesteak'
}, {
  name: 'hamburger'
}, {
  name: 'pork roll'
}];

var jawn = myArray.map(function(v) {
  return v.name
}).join();


console.log(jawn);
```

Comment: It's a bit funny that you are concerned about `.map()` not existing in older browsers, but you're using the arrow function.  `.map()` is good back to IE9, but it's the arrow function that would run into browser support issues long before that.  So, just switch to using a old-fashioned anonymous function for your `.map()` and browser support will improve a lot.  There is zero reason that an arrow function or any ES6 capability needs to be used here, so I'm surprised that is a prominent part of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each element to a single property and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) those:

```js
var myArray = [{
  name: 'cheesesteak'
}, {
  name: 'hamburger'
}, {
  name: 'pork roll'
}];

var jawn = myArray.map(function(it) {
  return it.name;
}).join();

console.log(jawn);
```

Answer (score 2):

**[lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) (v4):**

```
var result = _.map(myArray ,'name').join(',');
```

**[underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/):**

```
var result = _.pluck(myArray ,'name').join(',');
```